# ASP MVC 4 Интегрировать  simogeo/Filemanager в ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Ребят есть отличный файл менеджер: https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager

там есть коннектор для ASP MVC подскажите как его интегрировать? Я сделал по тем шагам, что на оф странице, но не работает. Понимаю что нужно затратить время, отблагодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Если тема еще актуальна, то есть решение.

1. Скачать сам файл-менеджер: https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager.
2. Подключить его в проект MVC 4. Я включил в папку `Scripts` под его собственным именем - папка `Filemanager-master`.
3. Остается только прописать это имя в файле `filemanager.ashx`, указав путь к картинкам: `public string IconDirectory = "/Scripts/Filemanager-master/images/fileicons/"; // Icon directory for filemanager`.
4. И внести изменения в `filemanager.config.js` (`.default` отрезать), задав корневую папку, у меня `Content` (`"fileRoot": "/Content/"`), язык (`"culture": "ru"`) и контекст выполнения (`"lang": "ashx"`).
5. В представление `Index.cshtml` кинуть кнопку с вызовом всего подключенного хозяйства:

```
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Open File Manager" onclick="OpenFileMngr();" />
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenFileMngr() {
        var mngrWnd = window.open("/Scripts/Filemanager-master/index.html", "File Manager", 'location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,directories=no,status=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=750, false');
    };
</script>
```

Похоже здесь файл к сообщению не прицепишь, поэтому проект качайте с яндекс-диска: http://yadi.sk/d/E4uoOr4uRFwDQ

Буду рад, оказаться полезным (по текущей теме), еще более буду доволен собой, получив не только моральную поддержку: dt0301@yandex.ru

По поводу ссылки на проект. Только что скачал дважды сам, пользуясь яндекс-браузером и firefox. Если есть свой янд. диск, жмите первую кнопку и сохраняйте проект на него, иначе - вторую, тогда сохраните на комп.

Я вчера не посмотрел, что все это для CKEditor, за наших болел.
Все так же легко впаивается!
Ссылка на проект (ваял в VS 2013): http://yadi.sk/d/yPA7rw6eRK2QQ
В проекте инструкция. В настройках все очевидно.